# why nginx adopt multiprocess rather than multithreads

Tags: node.js, multithreading, nginx, multiprocessing, netty

I was wondering why nginx do not use thread pool, cause its cause less waste when scheduling by processor.
Node.js can not use multithreads efficiently because the design of libuv and V8. So they got cluster
But why nginx?
Just like netty in Java. main reactor and subreactors. is it more efficient?
is there any documents from nginx or arguments from other people?
I really want to know the reason why

I've searched some in google, but I did not get some useful ideas. so does stackoverflow